# Force Access to accept Table.* in SELECT, GROUP BY, and ORDER BY?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I  have the following query on a table TheTable.  For each record, it finds all records having the same Field1 and Field2, and having lesser value in Field3, then sums up Field5.

```
SELECT OuterQuery.Field1,
       OuterQuery.Field2,
       OuterQuery.Field3,
       OuterQuery.Field4,
       OuterQuery.Field5,
       SUM(InnerQuery.Field5) AS Accumulate5
FROM TheTable OuterQuery INNER JOIN TheTable InnerQuery
ON InnerQuery.Field1  = OuterQuery.Field1 AND
   InnerQuery.Field2  = OuterQuery.Field2 AND
   InnerQuery.Field3 <= OuterQuery.Field3
GROUP BY OuterQuery.Field1,
         OuterQuery.Field2,
         OuterQuery.Field3,
         OuterQuery.Field4,
         OuterQuery.Field5
ORDER BY OuterQuery.Field1,
         OuterQuery.Field2,
         OuterQuery.Field3,
         OuterQuery.Field4,
         OuterQuery.Field5
```

For such a simple function, this is very tedious to code up and to cognitively parse.  The SELECT, GROUP BY, and ORDER BY clauses could conceptually be replaced by OuterQuery.*, but Access doesn't accept that.  I don't suppose there is an app switch or a coding idiom that *will* allow for such elegant wild card-ing?  The above code gets even uglier if you have to FORMAT one of the fields, since the FORMAT expression is also replicated.

I've posted this to:

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31952074/force-access-to-accept-table-in-select-group-by-and-order-by)
- [Microsoft Community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-access/force-access-to-accept-table-in-select-group-by/7f4869f6-c777-4da3-b2ee-ee21acc47088?tm=1439327578884)

Comment: With a group by clause NO DATABASE engine accept that. Perhaps MySql.

Comment: * is a bad habit :) better to get out of it now

Comment: Jorge: Do you mean that no DB engine will accept GROUP BY followed by the wild card asterisk?  Is there another way to achieve the same effect of avoiding the repetition?

Holmes: Why is it bad?